# A weird intellisense error for std::vector<T*, std::allocator<T*>> in visual c++ 2012

Tags: c++, vector, intellisense, visual-c++-2012

When I wrote this simple code in Visual C++ 2012, I got an interesting intellisense error:
a reference of type

```
"std::vector<Node*, std::allocator<Node*>> &" (non const-qualified)
```

cannot be initialized with a value of type

```
"std::vector<Node*, std::allocator<Node*>>".
```

But we can build the code successfully with no warning and error. So why Visual C++ 2012 reports such an intellisense error?

```
#include <vector>

using std::vector;

class Node {
private:
    vector<Node*> children; 
public: 
    vector<Node*>& getChildren() {
        return children;
    }

    void addChild(Node* child) {
        children.push_back(child);
    }
};

void f(Node* root)
{
    vector<Node*>& tmp = root->getChildren(); // intellisense error on 'root' here
}

void main()
{
    Node root;
    Node child1, child2;
    root.addChild(&child1);
    root.addChild(&child2);
    f(&root);   
}
```

Comment: [Cannot reproduce](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/437c2a39dea07d50). Must be a bug of some sort.

Comment: Intellisense is not a compiler -- it is just a tool.  It is susceptible to bugs just like any other tool.